# How to unit test $location service search() method, in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

How to create a unit test of AngularJS $location service search() method?

I am using Jasmine+Karma for the test and AngularJS 1.3, and unit test is new to me :)

This is my service, which is working fine in production btw:

```
'use strict';
(function () {
angular.module('myApp')
   .service('myService', function ($location) {
      var _customerId = $location.search().id;
      /*jshint validthis:true */
      this.customerId = _customerId;
   });
})()
```

And this is my serviceSpec:

```
describe('Service: mySerivce', function(){

 var $location;

 beforeEach(module('myApp'));

 beforeEach(inject(function(_$location_){
  $location = _$location_;
 }));

 it('should get ID from url', function(){
   $location.path('/?id=1080');

   console.log($location.path()); // logs: '/?id=1080'
   console.log($location.search().id); // logs: undefined

   expect($location.search().id).toEqual(1080); // Returns err msg Expected undefined to equal 1080.
  })

});
```

When i use the search() method all I get is undefined? How can i use the method in a unit test?

Comment: Yes, then I'm still getting undefined. How can I test customerId instead?

Comment: First of all the test you are doing doesn't make much sense, you just tests $location.path itself which is already tested by AngularJS ;)
for the $location.search() to reflect changes you might need to run $scope.$digest() or use spyOn to test the values

Comment: Will look into spyOn :) The reason i'm testing the search method, is because i want to use it for another test. The test is with  $httpBackend, where I need the ID in a GET request.

Comment: to test controller that uses search you can do: `spyOn($location, 'search').andReturn({id: 'mockedid'})` where you can check if calls to backend contains this mockedid

Comment: Cool, let me combine my comments into answer so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per comments you need a `$location.search().id` to check controller functionality, in that case the best option is to use `spyOn` on injected service (any service really)

```
spyOn($location, 'search').andReturn({ id: mockedid })
```

and remember that some of the services/directives needs `$scope.digest()` to be triggered and change value

Comment: Just a note for others who might read this, if you are working with Jasmine version 2.0+, it is .and.returnValue() and not .andReturn()

Comment: spyOn($location, 'search').andCallFake(function() {}); // also handy!