# Setting $location.search on AngularJS unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner

For some reason when I try to set param with...

```
$location.search('id', 2);
```

... on AngularJS unit tests (Karma + PhantomJS), it doesn't set, even with $apply set. And if I test it straight away...

```
expect($location.search().id).toEqual(2);
```

... it would give me that ID is undefined.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test $location service search() method, in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360814/how-to-unit-test-location-service-search-method-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Try spy

```
 spyOn($location, 'search').and.returnValue({
        id:2
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.